# Change display of item count in cart

Tags: magento2, cart

Is there any way to change the count of items displayed beside the cart icon?

Currently if I add 2 products with an item count of 100 each this count shows 200. Our customer would like it to only display 2 in this example (as in 2 different products).

[image: screenshot of the count of items in a cart]

I would be open to overriding Magento core functions, if that is necessary to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can display number of items instead of number of qty, apply below setting and check

> ```
> Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> My cart link
> >> Display Cart Summary >> Display number of items in cart >> Save.
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't think it would be that easy :)